# phpMyAdmin on MAMP local server hangs when importing table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to import the wp_posts table into a database for a Wordpress site hosted locally using MAMP, but when I start the import, phpMyAdmin seems to hang; I don't get any errors or anything at all. When I inevitably have to refresh the browser, phpMyAdmin is completely frozen and I can't navigate anywhere without restarting MAMP.

Strangely, the table I went to import was already named wp_posts, which already existed in the database. It's my understanding that this should have thrown an error since the table already existed, but after phpMyAdmin was hung, and I restarted the server, wp_posts did exist but all rows had been erased, so basically the action just wiped out the table, and that's all that has happened.

The .sql file is 18MB, so I upped the max upload limit, so I know that's not a problem.

What would be causing this and how could I remedy it?

Comment: i'd workarond the problem with phpadmin by doing the import using the mysql command line client, and not mess with phpmyadmin.

Comment: the workaround worked, thanks